# Python pyramid structure

Tags: python, python-3.x

**How to print pyramid like this in Python 3.x.x ?**

I want to design a pyramid of n size 1st one contains * increasing by 1 and 2nd contains * increasing by 2.

```
   *
  * * 
 * * * 
* * * * 
 * * *
  * * 
   *


   *
  *** 
 ***** 
******* 
 *****
  *** 
   *
```

## my code is...

```
n = 4  
for i in range(n):  
    for s in range (n - i) :   
        print(" ", end="")  
    for j in range((i * 2) - 1):  
        print("*", end="")
    print()  
for i in range(n, 0):  
    for s in range (n - i) :  
        print(" ", end="")  
    for j in range((i * 2) - 1):  
        print("*", end="")  
    print()
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is quite broad. As-is, it appears as though you're asking us to do your homework for you. Surely that isn't the case?

Comment: First you should send your code here, then we can give solutions if you did any mistakes. This community is not for write code for someone. Here's only you can get solutions of your problem not entire code.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious flaw is here:

```
for i in range(n, 0):
```

This loop stops before it begins, whereas you meant it to count down:

```
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
```

With that simple change your program outputs:

```
> python3 test.py

   *
  ***
 *****
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
>
```